# С помощью какого инструмента лучше всего создать радиальное (круговое) меню | CANVAS vs SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интересует вопрос, с помощью какого инструмента можно создать подобное меню? На чистом `канвасе` или прибегнуть к `SVG`, само **меню будет двух слойное**, при клике на один из элементов будет вылезать второй слой круга, что-то на подобие под меню.

На данный момент интересует **ТОЛЬКО** вопрос об инструментах.

С `canvas` все плохо, но если потребуется, то я изучу его, главное выиграть в производительности и качественности результата.

Comment: svg кажется достаточно

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо за ответ, если его достаточно, то воспользуюсь им